# How to successfully run existing T4 templates in VS2015?

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2015, t4, t4-toolbox

I am new to this T4 Templates.
All i know is these templates will generate entity classes from a LINQ to SQL class model (.dbml file)
We have this system which runs on Visual Studio 2010.

The problem starts, when we migrate to Visual Studio 2015.
I want to add new column to the entity/table. 
When i Run Custom Tool, this error pops

> A processor named 'T4Toolbox.XsdProcessor' could not be found for the
>   directive named 'xsd'. The transformation will not be run.  The
>   following Exception was thrown:
>       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Failed to resolve type for directive processor T4Toolbox.XsdProcessor.

Below is the template.

```
<#@ template hostspecific="True" debug="true" #>
<#@ xsd processor="T4Toolbox.XsdProcessor" file="%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\..\Xml\Schemas\DbmlSchema.xsd" #>
<#@ output extension="log" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>
<#

@ include file="..\..\..\Framework\Templates\LinqToSql.tt" #>
// <copyright file="Script1.tt" company="">
//  Copyright © . All Rights Reserved.
// </copyright>

// Generate entity classes from a LINQ to SQL class model (.dbml file)
NXpertGenerator generator = new NXpertGenerator();
generator.DbmlFile = "..\\..\\NXpert.Accounting.DataAccess\\Accounting.dbml";
generator.ConnectionStringKey = "AccountingDB2";
generator.DbmlNamespace = "NXpert.Accounting.DataAccess";
generator.UsingStatements = new List<string>{"NXpert.Core", "NXpert.Accounting", "NXpert.Accounting.DataAccess", "System.Data.Linq"};

generator.ClassMappings = new List<ObjectDescriptor>{   
    new ObjectDescriptor{
        Name = "BalanceSheet",
        NamePlural = "BalanceSheets",
        EntityName = "BalanceSheetEntity",
        Properties = new List<PropertyDescriptor>{
            new PropertyDescriptor{ Name = "Status", ConvertType = "CommonStatus" },
            new PropertyDescriptor{ Name = "CreatedDate", ConvertType = "DateTime" },
            new PropertyDescriptor{ Name = "UpdatedDate", ConvertType = "DateTime" }
        }
        }
};

generator.Run();

#>
```

I did try to  remove the  line

```
<#@ xsd processor="T4Toolbox.XsdProcessor" file="%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\..\Xml\Schemas\DbmlSchema.xsd" #>
```

This error shows

> Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'Association'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>       Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'Database' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Somewhat this kind of error tells me that it is just a namespace that i forgot to add.
But again this template is running perfectly in Visual Studio 2010.

There must be some settings/ steps to be done in order for these templates to run in VS2015. Please let me know.

I would gladly appreciate any solution or idea you can share to this problem of mine.